# Selecting all names with more than 1 code

Tags: sql, count, having

I have the following query, but it is not giving the expected results.

```
SELECT 
    FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME , ORDER_CODE 
FROM 
    CUSTOMER
HAVING 
    COUNT(ORDER_CODE) > 1
```

I want to see all combined first+last names which have 2 or more unique order_codes. How can I query for this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer might be product specific.)

Comment: Do you need the order_codes to be returned, or just the names?

Comment: Just the names should be fine

Comment: `FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME` is invalid standard SQL - which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `count(distinct)` as well as `group by`:

```
SELECT (FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME), ORDER_CODE 
FROM CUSTOMER
GROUP BY (FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ORDER_CODE) > 1;
```

This also assumes that `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` are never `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the name concatenation part up in derived table - to avoid duplicating the concatenation code.

`GROUP BY` its result and use `HAVING COUNT DISTINCT` to only return names with more than one different order_code:

```
select full_name
from
(
    select FIRST_NAME + ' ' + LAST_NAME as full_name, ORDER_CODE
    FROM CUSTOMER
) dt
group by full_name
having count(distinct ORDER_CODE) > 1
```